# how to generate machine Unique code by c# .net core in linux?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm build a website by asp.net core webapi,and we add license check our customer Authorized ,so want get machine info to generate unique id.

I should get cpuid+mac address + hard disk id to make the unique id , how can i do ?

we can get info by wmic in windows platform，but linux can't (ubuntu or centos).

Comment: Have you considered that some customers might want to containerize (e.g. Docker) your application?

Comment: _"but linux can't"_ - no, it's just you don't know how

Comment: You can get any info you want on a Linux OS. As someone who has written a lot of commercial software: don't make it overly complicated. Someone can and will crack it no matter how much work you put in to it. Just put enough in to "keep an honest man honest". Don't tie it to specific hardware: people get new computers all the time. People can change MAC addresses easily, hard drives go out, motherboards get swapped, etc. It's a tech support nightmare especially if you are new to this sort of stuff.

Comment: @vasily.sib no, Linux can't use WMIC. :)

Comment: @yaakov that'll be because the W in WMIC stands for Windows.

Comment: @yaakov I mean _"no, it's just you don't know how to get CPU id, MAC address and HDD id on linux"_

Comment: hi . Did you a find a way to get those Ids in Linux using .net core?